# Ios xcode6 :The code for reloading table through refresh control crashes on iphone but it runs perfectly on ipad

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, tableview

I am creating an application with a tableview.This is a universal application.It has a pull to refresh mechanism which is called to fetch data from a url and reload data.it works perfectly on ipad but the app crashes on iphone.I am getting the following error on iphone
         *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30668f83 0x3ae19ccf 0x3059f7cb 0x17f2ff 0x17eb71 0x32fb88f7 0x32f5fc27 0x32f5f47d 0x32e85d59 0x32b0362b 0x32afee3b 0x32afeccd 0x32afe6df 0x32afe4ef 0x32b51c49 0x358ca75d 0x31354451 0x30628ea9 0x30633a67 0x30633a03 0x306321d7 0x3059cebf 0x3059cca3 0x354a2663 0x32ee914d 0x19e325 0x3b326ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

```
    I am using the following code  for fetching data from net.the control does'nt go inside the completion handler of the nsurlsession it seems.I used breakpoints to check those things.please help me.i want to submit the code to appstore in two days.
 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
[[session dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:
  ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
  {

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^
                     {
                         NSHTTPURLResponse *resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

                         [LogRecords showLog:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"-------- >>>>> %li",(long)resp.statusCode]];
                         if(error)
                         {
                             [LogRecords showLog:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"-------- >>>>> %@",error.localizedDescription]];

                             [self.delegate seasonWithError:[self createErrorMessage:[error localizedDescription] errorCode:0]];
                         }
                         else if(resp.statusCode == 500)
                         {
                             [self.delegate seasonWithError:[self createErrorMessage:ERROR_500 errorCode:500]];
                         }
                         else if(resp.statusCode == 403)
                         {
                             NSError *parsedError = nil;
                             NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&parsedError];

                             NSDictionary *errorData =  [parsedObject objectForKey:@"Exception"];

                             [self.delegate seasonWithError:[self createErrorMessage:[errorData objectForKey:@"Description"]errorCode:403]];
                         }

                         else if(resp.statusCode == 401)
                         {
                             if(signinCounter == 0)
                             {
                                 [self signinUser];
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 signinCounter = 0;
                             }
                             signinCounter++;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             NSError *localError = nil;
                             if([[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError] isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
                             {
                                 NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&localError];

                                 if([parsedObject objectForKey:@"error"])
                                 {
                                      [self.delegate seasonWithError:[self createErrorMessage:[parsedObject objectForKey:@"reason"] errorCode:(int)[[parsedObject objectForKey:@"error"] integerValue]]];
                                 }
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 [self.delegate seasonWithJson:data];
                             }
                         }
                     });
  }] resume];
```

}

```
    It works perfectly on ipad.is there any problem with threading??pls help.
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your crash report is not related to the code you have posted. Did you try to debug, or setting exception breakpoint?

Comment: Can't find the reload in your code. Your problem is most likely that you return a value in `numberOfSections:` or `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` that does not match the number of objects in your backend. And when `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called it accesses an out of bounds index.

Comment: The control does'nt enter the completion handler of nsurlsession.It simply crashes after this code.But for ipad ,the control goes into the completion handler.Do u know the reason?Thanks for the reply.